# How to use Jetty IPAccessHandler to whitelist IPv6 addresses?

Tags: java, http, localhost, jetty, ipv6

I want my Jetty server to only handle requests coming from the localhost. I am attempting to do this by:

```
   ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
   context.setContextPath("/webapi");
   IPAccessHandler ipBlockingHandler = new IPAccessHandler();
   ipBlockingHandler.addWhite("127.0.0.1|/*");
   ipBlockingHandler.setHandler(context);
   final org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server jettyServer = new org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server(8080);
   jettyServer.setHandler(ipBlockingHandler);
```

Though, this only works for the ipv4 and if I add `ipBlockingHandler.addWhite("127.0.0.1|/*");` it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable by overriding IPAccessHandler and manually parsing the adddresses:

```
IPAccessHandler ipBlockingHandler = new IPAccessHandler(){
      @Override
      protected boolean isAddrUriAllowed(String addr,
                               String path){
          return addr.equals("127.0.0.1") || addr.equals("0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1");
      }
    };
```